# How do I get CPU metrics in Dynatrace API for a service?

Tags: rest, dynatrace

Dynatrace has a rest api to get statistics. In the console I can go to a host and view the processes running - for instance weblogic. From there I can drill in and see spring boot web controllers and their CPU utilization as a percentage. These are also available through the "services" section of the admin portal.

Im trying to automate reading these services and their CPU to compare multiple environments. Even though I can see the percentage of the service on the front end dynatrace admin portal I cant seem to find the right api to get the data.

I can see the results at the process level with ***/api/v2/metrics/query?metricSelector=builtin:tech.generic.cpu.usage*** but I cant seem to get it at the service level. For instance weblogic is one server and one process group instance but it has multiple web controllers (sometimes several per web application) and I would like to see the CPU usage for each.

Comment: you are writing "... for instance weblogic. From there I can drill in and see spring boot web controllers and their CPU utilization as a percentage". Are you really sure, that you see CPU usages per service in the UI? Can you please share a screenshot of this?

Comment: Will add some screens hots when I'm off vacation. But it's showing literally the controller class along with cpu. I assume it instruments anything with the @controller annotation in spring? No idea how else it would know our java class names.